# Launching external editor in GTKmm

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

i am writing (using C++ and GTKmm) a simple photo browser that is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/jjkrol/ZPR

Currently i am working on creating a button, which will allow user to open currently displayed photo in external editor (for example GIMP). Because of this, i have two questions:

- Are there any examples of using Gtk::AppChooserDialog class? I couldn't find any and it's hard to start working on choosing the editor without them.
- Most important question - i am thinking about a way to launch an application with photo in command line. The only solution that comes to my mind is using system() call to do something like this: system("gimp /path/to/current/photo.jpg"); , but it is probably not the best way of doing this. Anybody knows a better way? I would like to port my application to Windows someday and a more portable way would be great.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I _think_ Gio::AppInfo is probably what you should look at for #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for answers, gpoo and ergosys! In the end i decided to use `Gio::Appinfo` as it looks more OOP-like. If anyone would face the same problem - this is what i have end up with:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gio::AppInfo> editor = Gio::AppInfo::create_from_commandline("gimp", 
                                    "GIMP", Gio::APP_INFO_CREATE_SUPPORTS_URIS);
Glib::RefPtr<Gio::File> photo = Gio::File::create_for_path(
                                (*currentPhoto)->getPath().string());  
editor->launch(photo);
```

Of course choosing the editor with `Gtk::AppChooserDialog` is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of system, you might want to use [Glib::spawn_command_line_async](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/group__Spawn.html).  There are other similar functions that gives more control if you need it.

For examples, you might want to look the source code of an application like [glom](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/tree/).